# How to stop drawing a specific rectangle pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

My program is a 'Piano Hero' game in pygame which works in the same way as guitar hero except that it is for a computer keyboard and its based on playing the piano rather than the guitar. I am using a design similar to Synthesia for my interface where rectangles come down to a 'hitline' and you have to press the key at the right time.

My problem is that although the rectangles are drawing and working as intended at first, they do not seem to update so that the top ever stops. In other words, every note in the song is infinitely long.

I feel like this is probably where the error is although I am not 100% sure.

```
def Draw(self,hitLine):

    if self.coords[2][1]<hitLine:
        self.coords[0][1]+=2
        self.coords[1][1]+=2
        self.coords[2][1]+=2
        self.coords[3][1]+=2
    elif self.coords[2][1]>=hitLine and self.coords[0][1]<hitLine:
        self.coords[0][1]+=2
        self.coords[1][1]+=2
    else:
        self.drawing = False
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen,BLUE,self.coords,0)
    pygame.display.update()
```

This line is inside a while loop which just updates all of the rectangles in the song one at a time.

```
for z in notes:
        if z.drawing:
            z.Draw(hitLine)
```

Comment: Did you try to debug your program and check what are the values for `self.coords`?

Comment: Does the rectangle move correctly until `hitLine` is reached?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run and test, otherwise it's difficult or even impossible to find the bug.

Comment: Is it possible that you are not clearing the screen every frame? If so, you might be drawing your rectangles over and over again, producing a trail of rectangles that could explain the "infinitely long" notes. A screenshot or video link illustrating this problem would definitely help too.

Comment: I did think about truing to provide an example that you could test and run, but it would require me to give you almost the entire code. This is a link to what it is currently doing @CodeSurgeon
 http://sendvid.com/plbaki36

The rectangle does move correctly in the sense that the bottom of the rectangle gets closer to it, but we never see the top of the rectangle if you watch the video.

I did try to debug it and the coordinates do change correctly, but the screen isn't being updated to show what I have most recently drawn. The issue is what CodeSurgeon said, I just dont know what

Comment: to do about it. @loannes

Comment: @CedricZoppolo hopefully that is clear!

Comment: For anyone that is interested, I will leave a link to my full code. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

https://ufile.io/t0a3h

Comment: It is kind of hard to figure out without the code, but have you tried printing out self.coords to see if those are being updated properly? I suspect that they are and that is likely not the issue, but it is worth checking. It might be useful to see the rest of the `Note` class as well as your "main loop." Also, there is no need to call `pygame.display.update` everytime you draw something; it is sufficient to do that after you have drawn everything that frame.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon my previous comment left the full code? Also they are updating properly. Thanks for that last line - made life a lot easier but same issue still persists.

Comment: Did not notice that, thanks for pointing out the link! Looking at your code (can't run it of course since all of the assets are missing) under `while running:`, when you are in the game, it looks like you are forgetting to clear the screen every time. This leads to you seeing the rectangles drawn from all of the previous frames. Take a look at the answer that @MichaelO'Dwyer posted just now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found you're question quite fun to work on and is very interesting!

Some items to consider.

1. It doesn't seem that there is any reason to use a "pygame polygon" for your Note objects which are clearly rectangles. In my code below I used "pygame Rect" objects.
2. You're main loop doesn't clear the screen every frame.

In your main loop you need to clear the screen every frame. In my code I used Rect objects. The Note stops drawing itself when it's top hits the `hitLine`.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

gameScreen = pygame.display.set_mode((1100, 692))

hitLine = 500

class Note:
    def __init__(self, rect):
        self.rect = rect
        self.drawing = True

    def draw(self):

        if self.rect.y < hitLine:
            self.rect.y += 2

        else:
            self.drawing = False;

        pygame.draw.rect(gameScreen, (0, 0, 255), self.rect, 0)

fNote = Note(pygame.Rect(500, -550, 80, 550))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    gameScreen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    if fNote.drawing:
        fNote.draw()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Thankyou! I can't believe it was so simple. I kind of figured it would be something like this when CodeSurgeon said there was no need to update after every note because that was making my code really slow! Also, are there any benefits of using pygame rect? This is a college project and I have other things to add to it. Is it worth changing all my code now? Also, in your code the rectangle will stop drawing as soon as the top hits the hitline so the bottom is going to go past the hitline and be visible. I will link all of my game if you want to check it out so far!

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gzsiij4o81pqwri/AAARCEd4vc7TN5uyoAjdQu-Oa?dl=0

Comment: Using a rectangle is cleaner and will use less space in memory to store all the vertices in a 2D. I think it's only a small change anyway.

Comment: Also, in the game in think that it would make sense to have the note visible until the top hits the hitline. What you can do to stop the bottom of the note being visible is to render the notes first and then render that piano image you have just under the hitline over that and then only the top of the note will be visible. It's important that you only update the screen when you have drawn everything in the right order. Best of luck in college!